# Function of swift, taking another function of its arguments

Tags: swift

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: Int[], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}

var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, lessThanTen)
```

This is the example on *The Swift Programming Language*.

But in this example, I want to change

```
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
```

to

```
func lessThanBenchmark(number: Int, benchMark: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
```

---

so I also change this example to

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: Int[], condition: (Int, benchmark: Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item, benchmark) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanBenchmark(number: Int, benchmark: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < benchmark
}

var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, lessThanBenchmark)
```

However, I got an error.

```
<REPL>:155:28: error: use of unresolved identifier 'benchmark'
        if condition(item, benchmark) {
```

At last, I have to write like this style

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: Int[], condition: (Int, Int) -> Bool, benchmark:Int) -> Bool {
    for item in list{
        if condition(item, benchmark) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanBenchmark(number: Int, benckmark: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < benckmark
}

var numbers = [20, 19, 7,12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, lessThanBenchmark, 10)
```

How can I pass benchmark to condition just as its own parameter?

Answer (score 0):

benchmark is an argument of function.

```
condition: (Int, benchmark: Int) -> Bool
```

this line of code means that condition is a function that return Bool value and can takes two arguments: Int as first argument, and benchmark: Int is second argument.

You can call benchmark inside of condition.

smth like that:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: Int[], condition: (Int, benchmark: Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item, benchmark: 15) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

15 is a value that you want to use